# SPI Timing of WIZ850io

Tags: microcontroller, spi, clock, ethernet, timing

I can't understand the SPI timing diagram, I had search through various websites for timing diagram but I have no idea how to interpret this timing diagram of WIZ850io. I am currently trying to form a SPI connection between MCU and WIZ850io.

So,I have the following question:

1. What does Tov,Tdh,Tchz means?
2. Does understanding the timing diagram is crucial in powering up (not sure if it is the right term, but I want to read/write the data) the W5500 Ethernet Controller Chip within it ?
3. Does duration/period (red bracket) consider as don't care state?
4. According to https://www.wikiwand.com/en/High_impedance tri-state(aka Hi-Z) does not affect the circuit, if so what is the purpose of tri-state?

Any example given or website as reference/study material is highly appreciated.Thanks in advance.
[image: SPI Timing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you research a bit more, you will find, that you need to have a look at the [W5500 datasheet](http://wizwiki.net/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php/products:w5500:w5500_ds_v109e.pdf#page=61) for a full specification.

This will contain:

[image: full SPI specification]

Which should answer your first question.

---

2. This might be a misunderstanding, for powering up you'd have to look at the power on sequencing or reset timing. You need to understand the SPI timing diagram to understand how to set up your SPI communication correctly.

[image: reset timing]

---

3. Yes.

---

4. It allows you to share the line with other devices. Which is typical for a SPI bus. You can connect several slaves, so when one slave is not addressed (with the CS) it has to free the bus putting its MISO pin in HI-Z.